# Pandas: iterate through two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    price   time
0   1    2019-04-11 03:01:53.488000
1   0    2019-04-11 03:27:25.768000
2   1    2019-04-11 03:34:20.520000
3   0    2019-04-11 03:36:16.556000
```

What I need to do is when the column `price` is equal to 0, take the value at the same row in the column `time` and compare it with the value in the column `time` when price is 1.

In my example it would be something like follow:

```
        price   time                      time_diff
    0   1    2019-04-11 03:01:53.488000   
    1   0    2019-04-11 03:27:25.768000   03:25:33
    2   1    2019-04-11 03:34:20.520000
    3   0    2019-04-11 03:36:16.556000   03:01:56

etc...
```

Any idea how to iterate base on two different columns? I am a bit stuck! thanks

Comment: Does the `price` column always go `[0,1,0,1...]` or are there larger gaps between `1` values at some points?

Comment: No it is always [1,0,1,0,1,0,....]

Comment: Why is it `3:25:33`? Shouldn't it be like 25 minutes for the second row for example?

Comment: yes it can be 25 minutes indeed, I just need the time difference

Comment: Then you should be able to use `df['time'].shift` and `timedelta`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby `df.price.eq(1).cumsum()` since you say the pattern is always `1-0-1-0`:

```
u = df.groupby(df.price.eq(1).cumsum())['time'].diff()
df.assign(time_diff=u)
```

```
   price                    time       time_diff
0      1 2019-04-11 03:01:53.488             NaT
1      0 2019-04-11 03:27:25.768 00:25:32.280000
2      1 2019-04-11 03:34:20.520             NaT
3      0 2019-04-11 03:36:16.556 00:01:56.036000
```